# Unselect group of radio buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm using jQuery and I have a group of radio buttons all with the same name, but different value properties.

For example:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "thename" value="1"></input>
<input type = "radio" name = "thename" value="2"></input>
<input type = "radio" name = "thename" value="3"></input>
```

I want to make it so they are all unselected. Current state of my page has one of them clicked. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11):

```
$("input:radio[name='thename']").each(function(i) {
       this.checked = false;
});
```

not sure why the jquery prop doesn't work and this does...

Comment: Good discussion of [jQuery's `prop()` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/557612)

Answer (score 9):

As of jQuery 1.6, `$("radio").prop("checked", false);` is the suggested method.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work for me.  I tried it.  Also, what if I had other radio elements on the page and I didn't want to apply that behavior to them?

Comment: just try changing the selector. something like `$("input[name='thename']")`

Comment: I agree this just plain doesn't work, my (hidden) radio button doesn't get unselected (the chosen result is still passed in the form)

Answer (score 6):

Try using this: `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);`

Using jQuery's [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method can change properties of elements (checked, selected, ect.).

Comment: This worked whe I added one more single quote after the close bracket ---  $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);

Comment: @JimEvans Thank you.  I'm not sure why I haven't seen that until now.  I have edited the answer to have the closing quote.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple and works for me.

**Try this one:**

```
$('input:radio[name="gender"]').attr('checked',false);
```

**Try this one:**

```
$('input[name="gender"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted by @matzahboy worked perfectly.

Tried other ways but this one worked the best:

```
$(input[name=thename]).removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$(input[name=thename]).removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Didn't work, but both of these did:
$("input:radio[name='thename']").removeAttr('checked');
$("[name='thename']").removeAttr('checked');

The surrounding ticks are optional.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple and generic answer (I believe):
`$("input[name=NAME_OF_YOUR_RADIO_GROUP]").prop("checked",false);`

For this specific question, I would use:

`$("input[name=thename]").prop("checked",false);`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me;

```
$('input[name="radioName"]').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetRadio(name) {
    $('#form input:radio[name=' + name + ']:checked').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop("checked", false);
    });
}

$('#form input:radio').on('dblclick', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.prop('name');
    resetRadio(name);
});
```

This allows you to double click the radios to reset them.

Answer (score 0):

To unselect all the radios of a group called "namegroup", try this:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=namegroup]").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the uncheck and disabled radio button it will run the onchange function that will trigger the uncheck and disabling of the radio button, using each it will iterate the index of the radio button under the input name = 'radio-test-name' after that it will get the properties of the radio button and you can now set the properties adding to 'this' and setting it to true or false. I hope it will help, thanks!

```js
$('input[name="radio-choices"]').change(function() {
  let currentValue = $(this).val();
  if (currentValue == 'choices1') {
    $("input[name='radio-test-name']").each(function(i) {
      this.checked = false;
      this.disabled = true;
    });
  } else {
    $("input[name='radio-test-name']").each(function(i) {
      this.disabled = false;
    });
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<title> Uncheck radio button
</title>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choices" value="choices2" id="choices2" checked><label for="choices2">Can pick</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choices" value="choices1" id="choices1"><label for="choices1">Uncheck and disabled</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-test-name" id="test1"><label for="test1">TEST1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-test-name" id="test2"><label for="test2">TEST2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-test-name" id="test3"><label for="test3">TEST3</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.