# JQuery: register events on ajax generated event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Following code has been generated through ajax:

```
<div class="momento-rating-input">
    <div>Rate this post</div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="rateit" value="3" style="margin: 0 0.5ex 3px;" class="ratems" />Good
        <input type="radio" name="rateit" value="2" style="margin: 0 0.5ex 3px;" class="ratems" />Average
        <input type="radio" name="rateit" value="1" style="margin: 0 0.5ex 3px;" class="ratems" />Bad
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in Javascript/JQuery, I need to clear selected radios. I try following code.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ratems')){
        $(this).checked = false;
    }
});
```

Above code is not working. I know we should use JQuery `live` or `on` functions to register events on AJAX generated elements.

**However I don't want to register any event, but to clear radio buttons in on a different event, that is firing without any issue.**

How can I clear those radio buttons?

**Little context, if needed**: This code is implemented on a light box and pressing left/right keys change images. For new image, `rating` radio buttons should be cleared.

Comment: So when did you want to clear the selected radios? based on what event?

Comment: On image change event, that is triggered by `left`/`right` key. That event is working as image and comments are changing through ajax. Any ways problem was wrong code, corrected by accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to uncheck a radio buton with class name `ratems`

```
$('input[type="radio"].ratems').prop('checked', false);
```

instead of using `$('input[type="radio"]').each(..)`

Comment: Thanks @Sheik Heera, This is much better solution then what I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `checked` attribute from the element:

```
$('input[type="radio"].ratems').removeAttr("checked");
```

Comment: Thanks. I simple saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044301/jquery-unselect-group-of-radio-buttons and got the code from there, without giving it second thought. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You should try replacing `$(this).checked = false;` with `$(this).removeAttr('checked');`.